# C# - Windows forms keeps freezing using a timer loop for tcp listening

Tags: c#, timer, infinite-loop

This appearently freezes windows forms. I am creating a TCPListener to communicate with a game to echo into its console. It works on both sides, but windows forms freezes during the process. The timer interval is 100ms.

Where is mostly creates the freeze is where the comment line "here" is.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests. 
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        TCPString.addData("Connected a client...");
        if (client == null)
        {
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            if (client == null)
                return;
        }
        data = null;
        sentData = null;
        sentData = "Hallo";
        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        if ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) //"here"
        {
            // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
            TCPString.addData("Received: " + data.ToString());

            // Process the data sent by the client.
            data = data.ToUpper();

            if (client.ReceiveTimeout > 5000)
            {
                client.Close();
                client = null;
                return;
            }

            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sentData);

            // Send back a response.
            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            TCPString.addData("Sent: " + data.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            sentData = "Go away";
            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sentData);
            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Short version: "you're doing it wrong" (tm). The UI freezes because you're using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which raises the tick event on the UI thread. Calling `Stream.Read()` blocks the thread until some data arrives, hence the interruption. You could use a different timer, but the fact is you shouldn't be using a timer at all. Instead, use the async API: call `TcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()`, and when that completes get the `NetworkStream` _once_, and use the `ReadAsync()` and `WriteAsync()` methods on that object. Call those methods from an `async` method, and `await` them.

Comment: If you include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your scenario, it would be possible to provide a specific answer that shows how to use the async API correctly.

Comment: In case of programming GUI Software, where GUI is running as main thread, to do heavy operations without affecting GUI performance you need to do it in another thread (asynchronously).